# Trying to get imageview to move back and forth when clicked, no errors showing up in Eclipse, but app crashes

Tags: android, eclipse

I've been working on this side project and have been hung up on this part of it for a while.  I'm trying to separate as much of the code related to the boat imageview into the boat class as possible.  I'm not getting any errors and everything looks right to me, but the app keeps crashing when i try to run it.  Here is the Boat class:

```
package com.cannibal_photographer;



import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Boat extends ImageView {

ImageView boatimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
boolean state = true;


public Boat(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    boatimage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick (View v) {
            if (state) {
                moveBoatForward(-290);
            } else {
                moveBoatReverse(290);
            }
        }
        });
    }


public void moveBoatForward(int amount){
        boatimage.offsetTopAndBottom(amount);
        state = !state;
}

    public void moveBoatReverse(int amount) {
        boatimage.offsetTopAndBottom(290);
        state = !state;
}

}
```

Here is the main activity class:

```
package com.cannibal_photographer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {



        @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Boat boatobject = new Boat(this, null);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


}
```

I'm sure there is just something fundamental that I'm doing wrong, but I have no idea what it is.  Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

*EDIT*

Here is the layout.xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@drawable/redsquare" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:src="@drawable/redsquare" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:src="@drawable/redsquare" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:src="@drawable/greensquare" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:src="@drawable/greensquare" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton5"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton5"
    android:src="@drawable/greensquare" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageButton5"
    android:layout_marginBottom="102dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
    android:src="@drawable/boat" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="135dp"
    android:src="@drawable/boat" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the **LogCat:**

```
10-07 04:01:53.424: D/dalvikvm(2049): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 37K, 6% free 2556K/2712K, paused 26ms, total 29ms
10-07 04:01:53.444: I/dalvikvm-heap(2049): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.245MB for 2764816-byte allocation
10-07 04:01:53.494: D/dalvikvm(2049): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 3% free 5254K/5416K, paused 41ms, total 41ms
10-07 04:01:53.554: D/dalvikvm(2049): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 3% free 5285K/5448K, paused 3ms+22ms, total 62ms
10-07 04:01:53.604: D/AndroidRuntime(2049): Shutting down VM
10-07 04:01:53.604: W/dalvikvm(2049): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
10-07 04:01:53.614: E/AndroidRuntime(2049): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-07 04:01:53.614: E/AndroidRuntime(2049): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cannibal_photographer/com.cannibal_photographer.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-07 04:01:53.614: E/AndroidRuntime(2049):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
10-07 04:01:53.614: E/AndroidRuntime(2049):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
10-07 04:01:53.614: E/AndroidRuntime(2049):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-07 04:01:53.614: E/AndroidRuntime(2049):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
10-07 04:01:53.614: E/AndroidRuntime(2049):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-07 04:01:53.614: E/AndroidRuntime(2049):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-07 04:01:53.614: E/AndroidRuntime(2049):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
10-07 04:01:53.614: E/AndroidRuntime(2049):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-07 04:01:53.614: E/AndroidRuntime(2049):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-07 04:01:53.614: E/AndroidRuntime(2049):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-07 04:01:53.614: E/AndroidRuntime(2049):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-07 04:01:53.614: E/AndroidRuntime(2049):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-07 04:01:53.614: E/AndroidRuntime(2049): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-07 04:01:53.614: E/AndroidRuntime(2049):     at com.cannibal_photographer.Boat.init(Boat.java:22)
10-07 04:01:53.614: E/AndroidRuntime(2049):     at com.cannibal_photographer.Boat.<init>(Boat.java:18)
10-07 04:01:53.614: E/AndroidRuntime(2049):     at com.cannibal_photographer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
10-07 04:01:53.614: E/AndroidRuntime(2049):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
10-07 04:01:53.614: E/AndroidRuntime(2049):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
10-07 04:01:53.614: E/AndroidRuntime(2049):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
10-07 04:01:53.614: E/AndroidRuntime(2049):     ... 11 more
10-07 04:01:56.825: I/Process(2049): Sending signal. PID: 2049 SIG: 9
10-07 04:15:22.295: D/dalvikvm(2136): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 40K, 6% free 2556K/2716K, paused 37ms, total 40ms
10-07 04:15:22.315: I/dalvikvm-heap(2136): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.245MB for 2764816-byte allocation
10-07 04:15:22.365: D/dalvikvm(2136): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 4% free 5254K/5420K, paused 44ms, total 44ms
10-07 04:15:22.415: D/dalvikvm(2136): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 4% free 5271K/5436K, paused 9ms+4ms, total 59ms
10-07 04:15:22.455: D/AndroidRuntime(2136): Shutting down VM
10-07 04:15:22.455: W/dalvikvm(2136): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
10-07 04:15:22.475: E/AndroidRuntime(2136): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-07 04:15:22.475: E/AndroidRuntime(2136): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cannibal_photographer/com.cannibal_photographer.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #60: Error inflating class com.cannibal_photographer.Boat
10-07 04:15:22.475: E/AndroidRuntime(2136):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
10-07 04:15:22.475: E/AndroidRuntime(2136):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
10-07 04:15:22.475: E/AndroidRuntime(2136):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-07 04:15:22.475: E/AndroidRuntime(2136):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
10-07 04:15:22.475: E/AndroidRuntime(2136):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-07 04:15:22.475: E/AndroidRuntime(2136):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-07 04:15:22.475: E/AndroidRuntime(2136):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
10-07 04:15:22.475: E/AndroidRuntime(2136):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-07 04:15:22.475: E/AndroidRuntime(2136):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-07 04:15:22.475: E/AndroidRuntime(2136):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-07 04:15:22.475: E/AndroidRuntime(2136):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-07 04:15:22.475: E/AndroidRuntime(2136):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-07 04:15:22.475: E/AndroidRuntime(2136): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #60: Error inflating class com.cannibal_photographer.Boat
10-07 04:15:22.475: E/AndroidRuntime(2136):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:596)
10-07 04:15:22.475: E/AndroidRuntime(2136):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
10-07 04:15:22.475: E/AndroidRuntime(2136):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
10-07 04:15:22.475: E/AndroidRuntime(2136):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
10-07 04:15:22.475: E/AndroidRuntime(2136):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
10-07 04:15:22.475: E/AndroidRuntime(2136):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
10-07 04:15:22.475: E/AndroidRuntime(2136):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
10-07 04:15:22.475: E/AndroidRuntime(2136):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
10-07 04:15:22.475: E/AndroidRuntime(2136):     at com.cannibal_photographer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
10-07 04:15:22.475: E/AndroidRuntime(2136):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
10-07 04:15:22.475: E/AndroidRuntime(2136):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
10-07 04:15:22.475: E/AndroidRuntime(2136):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
10-07 04:15:22.475: E/AndroidRuntime(2136):     ... 11 more
10-07 04:15:22.475: E/AndroidRuntime(2136): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
10-07 04:15:22.475: E/AndroidRuntime(2136):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
10-07 04:15:22.475: E/AndroidRuntime(2136):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:431)
10-07 04:15:22.475: E/AndroidRuntime(2136):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:561)
10-07 04:15:22.475: E/AndroidRuntime(2136):     ... 22 more
10-07 04:15:27.784: I/Process(2136): Sending signal. PID: 2136 SIG: 9
10-07 04:21:26.554: D/dalvikvm(2205): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 44K, 7% free 2556K/2720K, paused 29ms, total 31ms
10-07 04:21:26.564: I/dalvikvm-heap(2205): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.245MB for 2764816-byte allocation
10-07 04:21:26.624: D/dalvikvm(2205): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 4% free 5254K/5424K, paused 51ms, total 51ms
10-07 04:21:26.674: D/dalvikvm(2205): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 4% free 5257K/5424K, paused 3ms+3ms, total 54ms
10-07 04:21:26.714: D/AndroidRuntime(2205): Shutting down VM
10-07 04:21:26.714: W/dalvikvm(2205): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
10-07 04:21:26.734: E/AndroidRuntime(2205): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-07 04:21:26.734: E/AndroidRuntime(2205): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cannibal_photographer/com.cannibal_photographer.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #60: Error inflating class com.cannibal_photographer.Boat
10-07 04:21:26.734: E/AndroidRuntime(2205):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
10-07 04:21:26.734: E/AndroidRuntime(2205):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
10-07 04:21:26.734: E/AndroidRuntime(2205):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-07 04:21:26.734: E/AndroidRuntime(2205):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
10-07 04:21:26.734: E/AndroidRuntime(2205):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-07 04:21:26.734: E/AndroidRuntime(2205):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-07 04:21:26.734: E/AndroidRuntime(2205):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
10-07 04:21:26.734: E/AndroidRuntime(2205):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-07 04:21:26.734: E/AndroidRuntime(2205):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-07 04:21:26.734: E/AndroidRuntime(2205):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-07 04:21:26.734: E/AndroidRuntime(2205):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-07 04:21:26.734: E/AndroidRuntime(2205):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-07 04:21:26.734: E/AndroidRuntime(2205): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #60: Error inflating class com.cannibal_photographer.Boat
10-07 04:21:26.734: E/AndroidRuntime(2205):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:596)
10-07 04:21:26.734: E/AndroidRuntime(2205):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
10-07 04:21:26.734: E/AndroidRuntime(2205):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
10-07 04:21:26.734: E/AndroidRuntime(2205):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
10-07 04:21:26.734: E/AndroidRuntime(2205):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
10-07 04:21:26.734: E/AndroidRuntime(2205):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
10-07 04:21:26.734: E/AndroidRuntime(2205):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
10-07 04:21:26.734: E/AndroidRuntime(2205):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
10-07 04:21:26.734: E/AndroidRuntime(2205):     at com.cannibal_photographer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
10-07 04:21:26.734: E/AndroidRuntime(2205):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
10-07 04:21:26.734: E/AndroidRuntime(2205):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
10-07 04:21:26.734: E/AndroidRuntime(2205):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
10-07 04:21:26.734: E/AndroidRuntime(2205):     ... 11 more
10-07 04:21:26.734: E/AndroidRuntime(2205): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
10-07 04:21:26.734: E/AndroidRuntime(2205):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
10-07 04:21:26.734: E/AndroidRuntime(2205):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:431)
10-07 04:21:26.734: E/AndroidRuntime(2205):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:561)
10-07 04:21:26.734: E/AndroidRuntime(2205):     ... 22 more
```

Here is an updated version of the Boat class:

```
package com.cannibal_photographer;



import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Boat extends ImageView {


boolean state = true;


public Boat(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}
private void init()
{
    this.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick (View v) {
            if (state) {
                moveBoatForward(-290);
            } else {
                moveBoatReverse(290);
            }
        }
    });
}



public void moveBoatForward(int amount){
    this.offsetTopAndBottom(amount);
    state = !state;
}

public void moveBoatReverse(int amount) {
    this.offsetTopAndBottom(amount);
    state = !state;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few ideas here:

In your Boat view, override all 3 constructors:

Code sample:

```
public Boat(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public Boat(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public Boat(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

private void init()
{
boatimage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick (View v) {
            if (state) {
                moveBoatForward(-290);
            } else {
                moveBoatReverse(290);
            }
        }
        });
    }
}
```

I find this a general good practice when extending views.

1. It would be best if you included your Boat view in the layout.xml file, that way your inflation process can handle instantating your Boat view
2. If you must instantate your boat via the code, use the 1st Constructor. I believe the fact that your sending null as the AttributeSet is what's causing the crash.
3. Unrelated to your problem, but you have two methods: moveBoatForward & moveBoatReverse that practically do the same thing. This is duplicate code and is considered a very bad practice while coding. Try to think of a way to merge these two methods into one, then calling the same method, once with a positive number and once with a negative number.

EDIT:

Here's why your crash is happening:

ImageView boatimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

You're trying to find a view before the view was given its context.
To understand how to achieve the behavior you're looking for, it would be best if you posted your layout.xml file.

EDIT:

Considering your layout, here's the changes you should make:

Turn your ImageView into a Boat:

```
<com.cannibal_photographer.Boat
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageButton5"
    android:layout_marginBottom="102dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
    android:src="@drawable/boat" />
```

In your Activity, instantate the boat like this:

```
Boat boatobject = (Boat)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I tried using the first constructor, but it still crashes.  Thank you for the tips on better practice with my programming though.

Comment: I think I see how you could be right, but I'm not sure how exactly to reconcile the problem.  I have updated the post with my xml layout.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: I was hoping to report that that solved the problem, but it still crashes.  I've added the error report to the post if that helps.

Comment: in the init method, remove the boatimage reference with "this" (this.setOnClick...)

Comment: If I understood you right, I did as you said.  I've updated the post to include a revised version of the Boat class to make sure we're on the same page.  Unfortunately it is still crashing.  I don't need to declare the Boat class in the manifest file or anything do I?

Comment: Wow, I apologize.  I didn't think all three were necessary if I was just calling one.  That fixed the problem, it works exactly as I wanted it to.  Thank you very much!